# Java for loop increment by one unless between x9 - x99

Tags: java, for-loop

I want, in a for loop, to iterate between `0 - 10000` but want only to use the first ten indices from each one hundred block and ignore the other 90. Example if `i` is my index, I want to use the values `0 - 9` and jump to `100 - 109` and then to `200 - 209`. It looks relative simple but I am struggling how to do (what to put instead of `i++`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    // do something only with 0 - 9, 100 - 109 , 200 - 209, ....
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be more readable using two nested loops? Outer one makes the big jump (`i+=100`), inner one goes from 0 to 9 (`j++`), then `i + j` is your index.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the hint I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    //print/store i value
    if(i % 10 == 9){
        i +=91;
}
```

or nested loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i+=100) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 10;j++){
       //print/store (i+j) value
    }
}
```